# Error initiating Equalizer,my app crashes sometimes

Tags: android

So i was trying to use equalizer but sometimes app crashes

Here are the necessary things to note

## 1) I am using sessionid 0;

## 2) App crashes when any other app is either using it,or has used it and i haven't restarted the phone since then

Strangely the line number which is causing the crash is not shown

here is the logcat

```
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/AudioEffect(31157): set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -38
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/AudioEffects-JNI(31157): AudioEffect initCheck failed -5
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/dalvikvm(31157): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference 0x1d2002b2 (index 172 in a table of size 172)
04-30 18:21:29.642: E/dalvikvm(31157): VM aborting
04-30 18:21:29.642: A/libc(31157): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 31157 (thermusicplayer)
```

Comment: What about stop using sessionid 0 and attach it to your mediaplayer? session id 0 is deprecated

Comment: yes i know,but sometimes it runs,why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a different equalizer code and that helped

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.java